# Check if user is registered on other website

Tags: php

I have a txt file with the emails and password of some users like the following example:

**Email**           : **Password**

1. someemail@asd.co|12345
2. other@dd.bg|123

I retrieve the data in  this way:

```
<?php
$lines = file("raeercom2016.txt");
$data = array_map(function($v){
    list($email, $password) = explode("|", $v);
    return ["email" => $email, "password" => $password];
}, $lines);

foreach($data as $user){
   echo $user["email"];
   echo $user["password"];
}
```

I want to check if each user is registered in specific website like: **www.amazon.de**

I've tried a few things but without success. Can anyone suggest me any examples ?

Comment: why would amazon want anybody to know who's registered on their site and who's not?

Comment: It's an example. In my txt file i have over 100 users and want to save only the registered users in the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to check if each user is registered in specific website like: www.amazon.de

There is no general way you can programmatically check that on the websites of your choice unless they provide you with an API for that, which most of them wont. Any such endeavor is a waste of time

Answer (score 2):

If it smells like hacking ... it is hacking ! 
No website allows you to retrieve their users and passwords, and it will def not work with a simple php script like yours.

Comment: checking if the user exists on a site is not hacking, technically.